# Trial version for javaFx application

Tags: javafx, installation, license-key, trialware

i created my project on javaFx and also i generated a license key for it but i want to limit this licence after 30 days.I have do it with registry value storing the date with adding 30 days. but i found that if the user change the system date before 30 days my logic does not work.

so is there any solution or way for the trial version software without checking system date and allow only 30 days of trial ?

Comment: only distribute the client. have the business logic (which performs the check) run on your server

Comment: I can't understand you.Any details please!

Comment: run the actual logic on your remote server, which is contacted by the client applications. other than that, there is no water proof check possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add license4j external application with your project... it will work... check the documents and videos in youtube.